# Use of this in javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor tag as below :

```
<a  href='#' class='control_next_photo'>></a>
```

I have set an event on click of the above anchor as follows:

```
 $('a.control_prev_photo').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
    return false;
  });
```

Below is the moveLeft function.

```
 function moveLeft() {
    $('#post-text-slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#post-text-slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#post-text-slider ul');
        $('#post-text-slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};
```

Now my concerns is that the above is working perfectly when there is only one "post-text-slider" DIV inside which we have an anchor tag. when a user is clicking on the anchor tag the moveLeft() is getting called which in turn moving the slide to left.

But actually, I have several "post-text-slider" DIVs inside which have their own anchor tag. Now in that case if a user clicks on the anchor tag, it will trigger the moveLeft() for all the "post-text-slider" which is not desirable.

Can someone please assist me with the solution for this.

Comment: `#post-text-slider` is an element ID.  Shouldn't your `div`s have unique IDs on the same page?  That should fix your problem.

Comment: Need more details about html structure to be able to set up correct traverses

Answer (score 0):

If I figured out correctly your problem I suggest you:

1. convert post-text-slider from ID to class
2. use $(e.target).closest('div.post-text-slider') to get the current div
3. pass to moveLeft as argument the div element

```js
var slideWidth = 100;

function oldMoveLeft() {
  $('.post-text-slider ul').animate({
    left: + slideWidth
  }, 200, function () {
    $('.post-text-slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('.post-text-slider ul');
    $('.post-text-slider ul').css('left', '');
  });
}

function moveLeft(element) {
  var ulEle = element.find('ul');
  ulEle.animate({
    left: + slideWidth
  }, 200, function () {
    ulEle.find('li:last-child').prependTo(ulEle);
    ulEle.css('left', '');
  });
}

$(function () {
  $('a.control_prev_photo').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveLeft($(e.target).closest('div.post-text-slider'));
  });
  
  // old one
  $('a.old').click(function () {
    oldMoveLeft();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.post-text-slider {
  width: 100%;
}
.control_prev_photo {
  appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none; font: menu; color: ButtonText;
  display: inline-block; padding: 2px 8px;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-text-slider">
    <a class="control_prev_photo">Click Me</a>
    <a class="control_prev_photo old">Old Click Me behoviour</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="post-text-slider">
    <a class="control_prev_photo">Click Me</a>
    <a class="control_prev_photo old">Old Click Me behoviour</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="post-text-slider">
    <a class="control_prev_photo">Click Me</a>
    <a class="control_prev_photo old">Old Click Me behoviour</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```